# How can we measure how much charge a conductor holds and how it is distributed?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

In practice, given a charged conductor, how can we find the charge distribution $\rho$?

If [Poisson's equation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Poisson%27s_equation#/Electrostatics) is invoked, then one should specify the method used to derive the potential $\phi$.

Small side question: Is there any other equation(s) when associated with Poisson's we can recover both $\rho$ and $\phi$?

Comment: Are you asking how charge distribution is measured or calculated?

Comment: Measured. But I would also like to know if we can calculate it using another equation, because Poisson's equation alone is not sufficient if we don't know the potential.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, [Kelvin probe microscopy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_probe_force_microscope) is an effective way to measure surface potentials (from which one calculates the charge density distribution) at the nanoscale.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks for sharing.